# Numerically calculating angle of 3 component vector with positive x axis.

Tags: geometry, numerical-methods

Suppose I have a vector $x=(x_1,x_2,x_3)$, I'm curious how I can calculate the angle between the positive x axis and this vector that is always defined.

Thanks

Comment: Just take a vector along the positive  $x$ axis and use properties of the dot product to find the angle between the vector you just defined and $x$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the dot product rule: If $\textbf{x},\textbf{y}$ are vectors then $\textbf{x}\cdot \textbf{y}=||\textbf{x}||||\textbf{y}||\cos\theta$, where $\theta$ is the angle between $\textbf{x}$ and $\textbf{y}$. For your application, you can let $\textbf{y}$ be the vector $(1,0,0)$. So you get $$\cos\theta=\frac{x_1}{\sqrt{x_1^2+x_2^2+x_3^2}}.$$

Comment: Perfect, I get what you mean 100%. Thank you for the response.